# Sample app not updating after code change and browser refresh? Build hangs Blazor

Tags: blazor

Real excited to learn about Blazor. Lots of potential here with this framework!

VS 2017 build 15.8.9 and VS extension for Blazor v 15.5.9 
Ok, so I'm going through the demo app (todo) after starting a new project using the asp.net core (hosted) template.

The first problem I'm running into is code changes not being reflected in the browser (edge, Firefox and Chrome).  However, if I stop the app (via visual studio) and try to start again, a build starts but just seems to go on and on.
If I stop the site via iis express in the system tray, stop the build, then re-launch, it builds fine and runs with the expected results of the code change reflected in the browser.

What can I check?

Does the same thing when dropping down to command line and using `dotnet run` from the blazor_do.server folder

Comment: I believe you need to have at least VS 15.9.x for the lastest blazor release

Comment: Ive made the correction, I was referring to the Visual Studio extension for Blazor and its build#.  Im using VS 2017 build 15.8.9 and VSIX for Blazor 15.7

Comment: Then you are not running the correct versions.. believe me it matters. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

`dotnet run` will not work, you need to use `dotnet watch run`

See also: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1428

And this: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/1704

For more tips on getting it to work

**EDIT:**
Also make sure your are running the correct versions from: https://blazor.net/docs/get-started.html

Most important:

- .NET Core 2.1 SDK (2.1.500 or later).
- Visual Studio 2017 (15.9 or later)

Comment: I upgraded to VS 17.9.3 and I already have .NET Core SDK 2.1.5, but I still get the same behavior regarding code changes.  I have to stop the the debugging session in VS and restart.  Simply making a code change, saving and refreshing the browser will not see the update reflected.